# Sum of $1/2x + 1/3x^2 + 1/4x^3...$ where $x \in (0,1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am trying to calculate: $1/2 \times x + 1/3 \times x^2 + 1/4\times x^3...$ where $x \in (0,1)$

It is easy to show this series converges but I cannot find the convergence value. The absolute and relative difference between 2 continuous elements are all different. Really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the series
$$ \frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$$
Integrate termwise to get
$$ -\log(1-x) = x + \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \cdots$$
Now divide through by $x$,
$$ -\frac{\log(1-x)}{x} = 1 + \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{3}x^2 + \cdots$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Multiply the series by $x$ and look at its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

We know that $$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}-\ldots$$ $$\implies \ln(1-\frac{1}{x}) = -\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{3x^3}-\ldots$$ $$\implies -\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})-\frac1x = \frac{1}{2x^2}+\frac{1}{3x^3}+\ldots$$ $$x[-\ln(1-\frac{1}{x})-\frac{1}{x}]=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{3x^2}+\frac{1}{4x^3}+\ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in (0,1)$ let $f(x)=1/2 \times x + 1/3 \times x^2 + 1/4\times x^3...$.

Then $xf(x)=1/2 \times x^2 + 1/3 \times x^3 + 1/4\times x^4...$.

Then

$(xf(x))'=x+x^2+x^3+....=\frac{x}{1-x}$.

Can you proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the sum you are calculating is $S(x)$, then $$\frac d{dx}(xS(x))=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=\frac x{1-x}$$
Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

Define
$$f(x)=\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
$$\int_0^xf(t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{n+1}}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n=1+x\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}n$$
Then,
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}n=-\frac{1+\ln(1-x)}x$$